# How to append each two divs to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I want to move each two elements (.item) inside a div with `class="parent"`. 
I tried with the following, but it doesn't work:

```
var parent = $("<div class='parent'></div>");
$("#list .item:nth-child(1), #list .item:nth-child(2)").appendTo(parent);
$("#list .item:nth-child(3), #list .item:nth-child(4)").appendTo(parent);
$("#list .item:nth-child(5), #list .item:nth-child(6)").appendTo(parent);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qem91cmb/)

Comment: Swap the first and the third `appendTo` line. I'll let you understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each two child element like this:

```
var childLists= $('.item');
for(var i = 0, l = childLists.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    childLists.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="parent"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

parent is a single cached element so each time you use it it will not create a new parent. Not sure if you looking for something like .wrap()? http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ or .wrappAll() http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

```
$('#list').children().wrapAll('<div class="parent"/>');
```

Comment: Yes, is that.. I want to wrap each two elements in a div.

Answer (score 1):

Store the childrens in an array, then create as many parents as needed and put them back in your list, here is the code:

```
var list = $("#list"),
    items = $.makeArray($(".item"));

list.html("");
for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) list.appendChild($('<div class="parent"/>'));
    $("#list div:last-child").appendChild(items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack) method as follows:

```js
$(".item:even").each(function(){
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='parent'></div>");
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
  background:silver;
}
.parent{
  height:100px;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  text-align:center;
  background:dodgerblue;
  }
.item{
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin:5px 0;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:without wrap you can get it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var parent = document.createElement("div"); 
parent.className = "parent";
x = document.getElementById("list");
parent.appendChild(x);
document.body.appendChild(parent);
});
</script>

<div id="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```